# What exactly is this SUMPRODUCT and MID formula doing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In an Excel spreadsheet I have text entries `H23`, `w67`, `P45`, etc. and I want to sum the numeric parts of these, i.e., `23`,`67`,`45`.

I have the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((0&MID($H2:$S2,1+ISERROR(LEFT($H2:$S2)+0),10))+0)
```

which does the job, but I'm not sure what it is doing, and I am loathe to use it without understanding it fully. Can anyone explain the formula?

Comment: Under the formula tab is an evaluate function button that walks you through the calculations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain SUMPRODUCT formula](http://superuser.com/questions/922256/explain-sumproduct-formula)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a single cell formula to avoid confusion.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((0&MID($H2,1+ISERROR(LEFT($H2)+0),10))+0)
```

1. Your sample data all start with a letter but the `ISERROR(LEFT($H2:$S2)+0)` is meant to look for either a number or letter as the first character and add *1* if it is a letter. The [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-BE3191EA-D332-43E4-BAC3-810C97773A22) defaults to a single left-most character and TRUE is considered *1* and FALSE is *0*. If the left-most character is alphabetic then an error will be generated by using it in any mathematical operation (e.g. *<character>* + 0) so *1* will be added to the *1* in the *start_num* parameter of the [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD) and it will start at *2*. If no error is generated then *0* will be added to the *1* in the *start_num* parameter.
2. The *10* is the maximum number of characters that the MID function will try to retrieve. There can be less available and it will retrieve those.
3. If there is no number at all, the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) is going to choke on trying to convert a zero-length string (essentially blank) to a number. To guard against this, a *0* is prefaced to the result returned from the MID operation.
4. The result of the MID operation (and the appended *0*) is a string, not a number. As long as everything has gone well, the result should be all digits. A string containing all digits can be converted to a true number without changing its numerical value by multiplying against *1* or adding *0*. e.g. If you add *0* to *"123"* you get a true number of *123*.

That is all of the internal operations. All you have to do is expand this to multiple columns and allow for array processing with the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) as a wrapper.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((0&MID($H2:$S2,1+ISERROR(LEFT($H2:$S2)+0),10))+0)
```

With the columns locked as absolute but the rows remaining relative, fill down for subsequent rows.

Comment: Will sleep on this but I think I understand. Thanks